# How do I turn these valves off and on?

Tags: plumbing

I have these valves under every sink and toilet in my house.  I always assumed that they just shut off by turning clockwise, but that doesn't seem to do anything at all (tried on two just now).

[image: water valve picture]

What am I missing? - thanks

Comment: It says pull to close.  Most valves do turn, but I guess you got special ones.

Answer (score 2):

If you zoom in on the picture you'll see "pull to close". So pull the white tab out and the valve will close, push it back in and the valve will open back up.

Comment: Geeze, never saw the words before now.  I did try pulling it but I was worried that I'd break the thing, it seemed pretty flimsy.... Thank you

Comment: Our house has some of those, and yes, they are a bit flimsy.  It's best if you hold on to the body when you push or pull the "knob" because the pipe is often not securely fastened behind the bulkhead.